# Clear password text field in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to clear the password text field each time the pop-up is shown. The pop-up contains the password field

I'm using below function in jquery to reset:

```
function resetPopupFormErrors() {
    $("div.errors").closest("tr").remove();
     ....
}
```

And I'm calling this function in fancybox on startup. How can I reset the password text in above function so that if the user has typed something in text field & closed the pop-up & then if user opens it again, I don't want that password to reappear....How can I do it using jquery in above function?

EDIT: If I look at the html view source after typing the password, the value is empty for that password field. How can we clear something that's not appearing in value field?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wouldnt you do it the same as clearing a normal text box?

```
$("#yourTextBox").val('');
```

Answer (score 14):

Why not just set the textbox's value to `''`?

```
$('input[type="password"]').val('');
```

Note that this resets *all* password textboxes. Use an `id` if you want to target a specific one.

Comment: Lol, 30 seconds makes little difference ;)

Answer (score 1):

Clearing a field is easy:

```
$('selector').val('');
```

The tricky part is going to be detecting that they close the window and that it's not the first time it has been opened.

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of this function everytime while closing the popup !!

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {                
    $('#id').closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("");
});
```